# JNLP Launch Error using Git Pages

Tags: java, github, java-web-start, github-pages, jnlp

I am trying to deploy a JWS application through github pages, but am running into a JNLP Launch File Error exception.

In my gh-pages branch, I currently have the .jar, .jnlp inside the root, then the main class is inside a src folder.

### JNLP

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://coyiutoc.github.io/ConcentrationGame/" href = "concGame.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Concentration Game</title>
        <homepage href= "https://coyiutoc.github.io/ConcentrationGame/“ />
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href = "ConcentrationGame.jar" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="src.ConcentrationGameGUI" />
</jnlp>
```

Is there something that I should be doing differently? I've managed to get it to successfully deploy on Tomcat, without the src. in main-class and localhost as the codebase. (I've tried a JNLP with and without the src in main-class for git, but both don't work).

I apologize if this is an otherwise trivial question, I'm very new to git pages and JWS in general.

### Error

```
JNLPException[category: Launch File Error : Exception: null : LaunchDesc: 
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What exactly does happen?

Comment: 1) Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: .. 3) According to where the class is located in the Jar, `<application-desc main-class="src.ConcentrationGameGUI" />` should be `<application-desc main-class="ConcentrationGameGUI" />` (the `ConcentrationGameGUI` is not in a `src` package, so leave the `src` prefix out).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually tried removing src, but it is giving me the same JNLP exception. Will try checking with your JaNeLA.